# Append binary data for image datatype in SQL server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to append binary data to column whose datatype is image in SQL server.
I herad it's possible for varbinary(max),but i want solution for image datatype.
If so,please provide me the code sample.

Comment: `IMAGE` has been deprecated - you should always use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

First, as others have said, you should use VARBINARY type instead of IMAGE.

Anyway, if you still want to use IMAGE, you can use [UPDATETEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3517w44b(v=vs.100).aspx) command like this:

```
DECLARE @Pointer VARBINARY(1);
SELECT @Pointer = TEXTPTR(Data) FROM TableName WHERE Id = @Id;

UPDATETEXT TableName.Data @Pointer @Offset @Delete WITH LOG @Bytes;
```

Consider:

@Bytes = the actual bytes you want to append

@Delete = if you want to delete what it may have in its bytes positions

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create Binary Data Stream  
    string filePath = Server.MapPath("APP_DATA/TestDoc.docx");
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
    br.Close();
    fs.Close();

--------------------
//insert the file into database

string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles(Name, ContentType, Data) values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery,conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "application/vnd.ms-word";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Note: ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.**

Comment: i don't want to insert,but i want to append/update to existing binary data like .WRITE method for VARBINARY(MAX)

Comment: You can overwrite but can't append

Comment: Use the Update sql statement instead of Select sql statement in strQuery  variable.